# FM demodulation problem in python - wow&flutter measurement

Tags: python, numpy, signal-processing

I'm currently working on an application which aims to measure wow&flutter of analogue audio devices. The key task is to demodulate the test signal. I found some code and some pieces of information about FM demodulation, but I still have some major issues. The code down below is my "test field", but it doesn't seem to be working good. The amplitude of demodulated signal increase in time, but I don't know why. I really hope for help, because understanding this problem is really crucial for me. Thanks for the help in advance.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import hilbert

sampling_freq = 44100
T = 1/sampling_freq
fm = 4
fc = 3150
ts = np.arange(0,1-T,T)
ts2 = np.arange(0,44098)
xm = np.sin(2*np.pi*fm*ts) # Modulating signal
mf=100 # Modulation factor
xc = np.sin(2*np.pi*(fc+mf*xm)*ts) #Modulated carrier



def fm_demod(x, df=1.0, fc=0.0):

    # Making complex signal from real values input
    z = hilbert(x)

    # Remove carrier.
    n = np.arange(0,len(z))
    rx = z*np.exp(-1j*2*np.pi*fc*n)

    # Extract phase of carrier.
    phi = np.arctan2(np.imag(rx), np.real(rx))

    # Calculate frequency from phase.
    y = np.diff(np.unwrap(phi)/(2*np.pi*df))

    return y


xd = fm_demod(xc,10,fc) # Demodulated signal
data = np.fft.rfft(xd) # Demodulated signal spectrum

fig, (ax1,ax2,ax3,ax4) = plt.subplots(4,1)
ax1.plot(ts,xm)
ax1.set_title('Modulating signal')
ax2.plot(ts,xc)
ax2.set_title('Modulated signal')
ax3.plot(ts2,xd)
ax3.set_title('Demodulated signal')
ax4.stem(abs(data),use_line_collection=True)
ax4.set_title('Demodulated signal spectrum')
plt.show()
```

[Plots from the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzn6W.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your modulation formula is wrong, this is the correct form:

```
xc = np.sin(2*np.pi*fc*ts+(mf*xm))
```

(also remember that "xm" is actually the derivate of the message)